# Moons of Ida Question? From the Xanth book

Tags: piers-anthony, xanth

It was resolved in the Xanth series that the 'Moons of Ida' are just one big loop and that you can actually come back to Xanth if you travel long enough.

What I don't get is **how** you would return to Xanth when you're only traveling through souls. That means that your soul loops back to Xanth, but you're actually separated from your body?

**So how do the Moons of Ida actually work?**

I know it was explained in the novel "[Air Apparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Apparent)" but I really didn't get it.

> *Hugo realized that the Random Factor had not learned about Ida’s
>   moons. "Princess Ida has a moon orbiting her head. That’s Ptero, and
>   on it is every creature who exists in Xanth, or who is likely to
>   exist. When Xanthians visit, they have to leave their bodies behind,
>   and just their souls go to Ptero. The souls condense into the little
>   bit of material substance they have, forming likenesses of the people
>   they are. So you and I are really tiny bits of condensed souls. When
>   they are ready to return, they just let those souls diffuse, and float
>   back to their sleeping bodies."*

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a little guessing here, because I can't remember exactly. I reread that book recently and I think there was a scene where one of the characters asked Princess Ida about their bodies and she said that they'd eventually just fade into the background material of that world. Also, I think that Sim bird deduced that what Ilene created was a link in the chain of worlds, not the world itself. That was backed up I believe by D. Gaia.

Here is where my guessing comes in and it's completely up to interpretation. If we understand that each "Moon" is a representation of a world, instead of the world itself, then you aren't actually leaving your body behind and getting smaller. You're spirit/consciousness/etc... is traveling to the next link in the chain, leaving behind a shell of inert matter that your spirit animated and kept cohesive. This matter would dissolve into the background if you didn't return in a certain time frame. There is no telling what that time frame was.

This is similar to the way that Che Centaur created "bodies" out of organic matter, so that dragons being imported from "Dragon World" could come and inhabit them, in 'Currant Events'. They weren't actual bodies, just shells that became the image of the dragon's spirit selves once they animated them.

My thought is that when anyone travels to a world in the link, they are in sprit form, kind of like sending packets of data over the internet. This is viewed by them as shrinking to fit the smaller world. This is probably just their mind providing an explanation because it's what they expect. It' also explains how all of the moons have days and night, regardless of when Princess idea is inside or outside of Castle Roogna. This phenomenon has been referenced by characters in multiple books. Once on the world, they pull together bodies out of a mass of background material.

I think that because these books always seem to take place during a very short window of time, that the characters original bodies simply didn't have time to revert into the background material. I also think that their may be some affinity, since they've been with this material so long. Maybe it hangs around longer. This could also explain why Hugo and Random couldn't make it into another body. It could also be a mental aspect where they didn't believe they could go into any body, but the one they left. That would be self sabotage that stopped them when they tried.

That's just my completely out there reasoning as to an explanation for all of this. I think it's possible that they could have formed bodies for Xanth the same way that they formed them for any other world. I'll try to go back and reference the book tonight. I'm pretty sure that they were basically solid when they went to what they suspected was Xanth proper. I believe that when Hugo and Random "merged" with their bodies, it actually just deleted the extra copy of them.

The real thing to consider here is how Piers Anthony will handle the potential ramifications of this information. We know that people can travel "down world", because the dragons did it in 'Currant Events' to repopulate dragons in Xanth proper. Even if you say that you don't really know which way they traveled up or down the chain, because they just short cut there, it doesn't matter. We know that you can make the complete loop, because the characters do. What is to prevent all the might-be's on Ptero from doing the loop and coming to Xanth proper. Maybe there is a governing force that controls the travel between the worlds. We're never told much about the chain or how it was created, just that it existed a long time ago and that Princess Ida just happened to become the keeper of the link. They stated in the books that the link would pass to someone else when she dies. I don't know how that will work with the Idas of the moons. Since they're all Ida's and it seems like at least one would die at some point.

Another theory I had was that each moon is an alternate universe. Each moon is like a hyperlink to a particular world. Kind of like how the stork works could go between the alternate universes to deliver babies. However, the stork works didn't seem to have good control over what universe was which. The moons would be a chain of specific universes that you'd be guaranteed to make it to.

This could also explain a world like Ptero where there are copies of everyone on Xanth and they can't live the blanked out year. The in-book explanation is that Ptero is the world where everyone that ever has been, will be, or could be lives and they can't see or remember what happened in the current year they're real selves are on Xanth, if they have any. Since the books seem to suggest that each world is it's on individual world, this could fit my theory. If there are an infinite number of universes, there is surely one where there is a copy of everyone on Xanth that can't see the current year of their life on Xanth proper. There would also be another universe where everything else matches up, but you couldn't see a single day of the "real" Xanth self. Or any other change you could think of for that matter. That's how infinite universes work. It just happens that this is the one that is linked into the hyperlink chain. Again, we don't know how or why it was created or why particular worlds/universes were chosen to be part of that chain.

Another question I have about the whole thing is how Xanth Proper became the defacto "real world". Every character that goes to a moon and is recognized as a Xanthian is held in reverence for being "real". We know that each moon is basically a self contained world. So why do they each think Xanth is "real" and they aren't. Maybe it was because there was a break in the chain and it just became "general knowledge" over the long period of time that Xanth was "real". It was at the end of the broken chain. So was Moondania, though, so I guess it was a 50/50 shot as to which was the "Real" world. Even though in reality it was a 100% certainty that Xanth was "real", because that's the world that Piers Anthony writes about.

Well, I know this is a late answer, but I hope you got some ideas out of my rambling thought.